# How to get effective background color of transparent element with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I have an element on the page that may be inserted in multiple different locations. It has no background color set but depending on the background color of where it's inserted I may want to make a couple of changes to it.

My question is: how to get the effective background-color for an element even if that background-color may have been inherited from a parent (potentially all the way to body).

Here's a simplified example where I would like to find the background-color of .color-me

```
<div class="cont">
   <div class="color-me">what's my background-color?</div>
</div>
```

And a codepen: http://codepen.io/evanhobbs/pen/FbAnL/

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. Or if it is it will be incredibly complex to implement. Why do you need this? I'm sure there must be a simpler way.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using spin.js (http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/) wrapped in a Backbone view and I need to pass the spinner color as an option on init. But the view may be inserted on both light and dark backgrounds so would need have a different color. Does that make sense?

Comment: @EvanHobbs, the complexity comes in when you need to start taking into account background images, gradients, `rgba` values, and opacity. It's relatively simple to get the color of the nearest parent with a non-transparent background color, it just might not be the actual color behind the element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible given some (pretty major) caveats. [zzzzBov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497418/zzzzbov) summed them up well in a comment on the question:

> ... the complexity comes in when you need to start taking into account background images, gradients, rgba values, and opacity. It's relatively simple to get the color of the nearest parent with a non-transparent background color, it just might not be the actual color behind the element.

With those caveats in place, basically you have to get the background color of the element and, if it's transparent, go to the parent element, and so on.

Different browsers have different views of "transparent", here's an example covering most of them: [Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gomnd)

```
$(function() {
  var bc;
  var $elm = $(".color-me");
  while (isTransparent(bc = $elm.css("background-color"))) {
    if ($elm.is("body")) {
      console.log("Gave up");
      return;
    }
    $elm = $elm.parent();
  }
  console.log("Effective color: " + bc);

  function isTransparent(color) {
    switch ((color || "").replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase()) {
      case "transparent":
      case "":
      case "rgba(0,0,0,0)":
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }
});
```

I'm not at all sure this is possible with all browsers, particularly not ones that give back an `rgb` (not `rgba`) value for the computed color.

Comment: actually it's not working for multiple items with the same class on the page, cause it shows the same result.

Comment: @Good.luck: This is sample code, and will only work for the first match of the given selector (there is, after all, only one in the pen). If you need to loop through matches, you loop through the matches and do this for each of them.

Comment: yeah, that one will work for all the elements, sorry, thought that you posted the exact code.

Comment: Thanks worked great! The only slight tweak I made was that if it gets to body without finding a background color it returns white...

Answer (score 2):

I much prefer jsfiddle but here is your updated codepen.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nhDGC
Added anonymous function so to use it just call `$('.yourselector').getBg();`

```
jQuery.fn.getBg = function() {
return $(this).parents().filter(function() {

    var color = $(this).css('background-color');

    if(color != 'transparent' && color != 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' && color != undefined) 
    { return color; 
    }
}).css('background-color');
};

$(function() {
  //console.log($('.cont').css('background-color'));
   console.log($('.color-me').getBg())
   $('.color-me').append($('.color-me').getBg());

   console.log($('.color-me2').getBg())
   $('.color-me2').append($('.color-me2').getBg());
 });
```

It filters parents + will return when it finds the background color existing.

Comment: This works well, but it's worth mentioning that this will not check the original element itself, so if you want that you can change the 2nd line to this: return $(this).parents().addBack().filter(function() {
Which then adds back the original element into the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elegant way of solving this problem (sorry, I prefer CoffeeScript). It starts searching from self, but you always can just use `$el.parents().each ->`.

```coffeescript
findClosestBackgroundColor = ($el) ->
    background = 'white'
    $.merge($el, $el.parents()).each ->
      bg = $(this).css('background-color')
      if bg isnt 'transparent' and !/rgba/.test(bg)
        background = bg
        return false
    background
```

**DEMO:** Use coffeescript.org to compile this to javascript and run this in a console on any page that has jQuery included.

Compiled code:

```
var findClosestBackgroundColor;

findClosestBackgroundColor = function($el) {
  var background;
  background = 'white';
  $.merge($el, $el.parents()).each(function() {
    var bg;
    bg = $(this).css('background-color');
    if (bg !== 'transparent' && !/rgba/.test(bg)) {
      background = bg;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return background;
};
```

Comment: you may prefer whatever but the question asked for Javascript so Coffee and Typescript dont count even if they can be transpiled to JS.